# mysql order by field staggered display

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I want to create a mysql query that returns a result that is ordered by a certain column. The twist is that I want the order to be staggered instead of alphabetical or numeric. Say values for column_x for all records are either 'a','b','c', or 'd'. Rather than the order being all 'a', then all 'b', … I want the order to be one 'a', followed by one 'b', followed by one 'c', etc. until it gets to 'd' and then starts over again. I know I can order by rand() but that's not really what I want. I've racked my brains trying to figure this out but to no avail. I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think need to be done:

1. Group your lecords by alphabet, add it as a column to your query result.
2. Create a rowrum for records in each group, use user defined varibles and logic in  [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/) example, to make sure numbers are reset for each alphagroup
3. Sort items in ascending order by the created rownum

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. I wound up using the example in your link as a subquery since its I couldn't set the variables as separate queries (wordpress get_results limitation apparently)